# Simple if statement question for record not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got the following statement:

```
@all_comments = Comment.find(@task.id)
```

The problem is, if there are no comments it throws a record not found error. How can I get this to fail silently, so it just returns nothing?

Comment: @task.comments should return you the list of comments, if there any otherwise an empty array, if you've setup the relationships properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you are trying to do can never work.

The line `find(@task.id)` will look for comments that have the same `id` as the `task` which is normally not how you set up relations.

Normally you would have a task, and a comments table, and the comments table would have a column called `task_id`. If that is the case, you could write your models as follows:

```
class Task
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :task
end
```

and then you can simply write:

```
@all_comments = @task.comments
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use AR, but I believe just:

```
@all_comments = Comment.find(:first, @task.id)
```

will return nil if there is no record found, unlike `#find` without any modifiers.

EDIT | There's a shortcut too:

```
@all_comments = Comment.first(@task.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your failure is a different one you expect. Your query asks for a `Comment` with the ID `@task.id` (which is the ID of the `Task`).

Your query should go like that:

```
@all_comments = Comment.where(:task_id => @task.id)
```

or even better

```
@task.comments
```

This should work if you have declared your relations accordingly, and allows some more options (adding comments, ...).

Have a look at the ["Rails Guides"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html), and there the ["Active Record Query Interface"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Answer (score 0):

The rails throws `RecordNotfound` exception for `find` calls. Use `find_by` calls to avoid this.

If you are trying to get a list of tasks by task_id then user the `find_all_by` method:

```
# returns an empty array when no tasks are found
@comments = Comment.find_all_by_task_id(@task.id)
```

Otherwise use `find_by`

```
# returns nil when no task is found
@comment = Comment.find_by_task_id(@task.id)
```